# How and where is wordpress adding mySQL content to database?

Tags: database, mysql

I am currently following this [steps](http://dan.doezema.com/2010/04/wordpress-domain-change/comment-page-1/#comment-9160) to change server and domain for my website. I have been exporting and importing mySQL from one data base to the other. I am about to delete the mySQL content of the database to replace it. I am scared that it will mess up my website.

How does Wordpress create mySQL content on the DataBase and how can I make it re-write the content. In other words: why do i need to export and import the data base from the previous website and not just allow the wordpress files on the FTP to generate the new mySQL content?

many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files on your server are the WordPress app, themes, and plugins. All page, post, widget, user, and plugin data only exists in the database.

When you create a page or post, add a user, leave a comment, etc., WordPress is writing that data to the database and nowhere else. When a visitor loads your website, the data is loaded from the database and inserted into your template for each page view.

Without the data in the database, the content for your site is irretrievably lost. This is why regular database backups are important, and care should be taken in moving the data.

Answer (score 1):

if you have a ready WP installation and want just use it to build site from screch without content you can do that. if wordpress can connect to MySQL db and don't found tables (i asume you already delete tham) it will ask you to install blog from scratch